# Python-Django-WSGI-Apache on windows - “ImportError: No module named site”

Tags: python, django, windows, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to connect django with apache on windows server  with the wsgi mod.
when I'm running httpd.exe , it shutdown immediately. 
in the error.log I got this :

```
[Thu Nov 17 00:44:19.918823 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 520:tid 452] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.9+.
[Thu Nov 17 00:44:19.918823 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 520:tid 452] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.11.
[Thu Nov 17 00:44:19.918823 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 520:tid 452] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) mod_wsgi/4.4.12 Python/2.7.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 17 00:44:19.918823 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 520:tid 452] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC10 Server built: Jul  9 2016 11:59:00
[Thu Nov 17 00:44:19.918823 2016] [core:notice] [pid 520:tid 452] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd -d C:/Apache24'
[Thu Nov 17 00:44:19.918823 2016] [core:debug] [pid 520:tid 452] log.c(1543): AH02639: Using SO_REUSEPORT: no (0)
[Thu Nov 17 00:44:19.918823 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 520:tid 452] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2308
[Thu Nov 17 00:44:19.918823 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 520:tid 452] mpm_winnt.c(429): AH00402: Parent: Sent the scoreboard to the child
[Thu Nov 17 00:44:20.043916 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 2308:tid 448] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.9+.
[Thu Nov 17 00:44:20.043916 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 2308:tid 448] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.11.
[Thu Nov 17 00:44:20.043916 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 2308:tid 448] mpm_winnt.c(1718): AH00453: Child process is running
[Thu Nov 17 00:44:20.043916 2016] [wsgi:info] [pid 2308:tid 448] mod_wsgi (pid=2308): Initializing Python.
ImportError: No module named site
[Thu Nov 17 00:44:20.059467 2016] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 520:tid 452] AH00419: master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.
[Thu Nov 17 00:44:20.059467 2016] [core:info] [pid 520:tid 452] AH00096: removed PID file C:/Apache24/logs/httpd.pid (pid=520)
```

my python version is 2.7.11
my apache version is 2.4.23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer to my question :
the apache server run the python , but not the right one.
I had to be specific with the path of python in the `httpd.conf` file, like this :

```
WSGIPythonHome C:/Python27
```

this indicates the path to the python.